# Fill a matrix with another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, fill

I'm trying to fill a matrix with another matrix in R same size

```
pivot_simplex_fract<-function(matrice){
  n_row_matrix_2<-nrow(matrix_Standard) #number of the matrix
  n_col_matrix_2<-ncol(matrix_Standard)

  for (i in n_row_matrix_2){
    for (j in n_col_matrix_2) {
      matrix<-fractions(matrice[i,j])
    }
  }
  return(matrix)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Could you share some more details about your issue? Is the code not working? If not, what exactly is the issue? What is the `fractions` function? Is this a function you wrote, or is it from some package?

Comment: Hi, there thank you for your time, i found that solution, my main concern was to fill a matrix with other matrices for example : let’s say you have a matrice M[5,5] i want to fill it with 2 matrices M[5,3] and M[5,2] fractions transforms floats into fractions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fractions` function from the **MASS** packages can work with matrices. You don't really need to use a double loop. Suppose you have a matrix as such:

```
X <- diag(5)/5
X
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
[2,]  0.0  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0
[3,]  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.0  0.0
[4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.0
[5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2
```

You can subset rows and columns easily enough.

```
MASS::fractions(X)[1:3, 1:3]

 #         [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #    [1,] 1/5    0    0 
 #    [2,]   0  1/5    0 
 #    [3,]   0    0  1/5
```

Comment: Hi, there thank you for your time, i found that solution, my main concern was to fill a matrix with other matrices for example : let’s say you have a matrice M[5,5] i want to fill it with 2 matrices M[5,3] and M[5,2]

Comment: Then use `cbind`.